# Is there a way to configure data grip to convert 'ssf' into 'select * from'

Tags: datagrip

I type a lot of sql select statements. I'd like to be able to configure datagrip to replace the character string 'ssf' into 'select * from '. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news, it is possible to configure DataGrip to replace a specific string with and expanded string! What other editors ([Sublime](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html), VS Code, SSMS, Azure Data Studio, [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-snippets.html)) call "snippets," DataGrip and other JetBrains products call "Live Templates" as described for WebStorm [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/01/using-and-creating-code-snippets/).

There is an existing snippet for what you ask to do, which when expanded will also leave the cursor in the correct location for you to immediately start entering the desired source.

As @moscas mentions in his answer, the live template `sel` is what you are looking for.

When `sel` is typed, followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or what your DataGrip "By default expand with" [setting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/settings-live-templates.html) is) `sel` will expand to

```
> `SELECT * FROM ...;`
```

The cursor will be where the ellipsis (...) is after the expansion. Other useful existing templates are listed [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/using-live-templates.html) and I recommend building muscle memory for `selc` and `selw.` I also created a `selt` for `SELECT TOP(10) * FROM ...;` and you should be able to create a new one with using the `ssf` string using resources linked.

[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/using-live-templates.html) are the other default snippets/Live Templates that ship with DataGrip and expand with default expansion:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                Abbreviation   |    Expands to                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| ins      |  INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES (...);"              |
| sel      |  SELECT * FROM ...;"                               |
| selc     |  SELECT count(*) FROM ... alias WHERE alias. ...;" |
| selw     | SELECT * FROM ... alias WHERE alias. ...;"         |
| upd      | UPDATE ... SET ... = ... WHERE ...;"               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

It is, go to *Settings | Editor | Live Templates* where you can create snippets.

But see that there are templates already!
So, `sel` is actually will be transformed into `SELECT * FROM`.

To try this, type `sel` and press **TAB**.